# How to add a hyper link to the end of the cell in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to use the API to call and create a cell in spreadsheets for something like:

> Hello, please use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70487441).

But I have only found:

```
       "userEnteredValue":    {
                                 "formulaValue":"=HYPERLINK('link.com','link)"
                              },
```

How can I add "Hello, please use this" to the start of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

5 steps:

1. Add "Hello, please use this link" to the specified cell. (Fig. 1)
2. Click on the text viewer thing (I do not know what it is called). (Fig.2)
3. Highlight "this link". (Fig.3)
4. Click `ctrl` + `k`. (Fig.4)
5. Paste the link and click "Apply". (Fig.5)

---

[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OJaT.png)

[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWwZI.png)

[Fig.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCdrO.png)

[Fig.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Y8k.png)

[Fig.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1jkL.png)

Comment: hey, I'm asking for API call and not UI wise, but thanks anyway